# Grab string from the last cell that isn't missing in SAS

Tags: arrays, loops, sas, data-manipulation

`HAVE` is a dataset of authors on pubs:

[image]

^note that auth50 is the last variable in the dataset.

`WANT` is a dataset where the first and last authors for each observation of`HAVE` are their own variables:

[image]

I do the following in a data step to create `lastauth`...

```
array auths {*} auth1:auth50;
do i=1 to dim(auths);
    if auths{1} NE " " then firstauth = auths{1};
    if auths{i}  = " " then lastauth = auths{i-1}; 
else lastauth = auths{i};
end;
```

...which I *thought* would iteratively write over `lastauth` until encountering the last `authX` variable, but the code does not retrieve the last non-missing value. Any thoughts on what I'm misunderstanding? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the logic carefully.  You want to set the value of FIRST when FIRST is missing and set the value of LAST when the current is NOT missing.

```
array auths auth1-auth50;
firstauth=auths(1);
do i=1 to dim(auths);
  if missing(firstauth) then firstauth = auths{i};
  if not missing(auths{i}) then lastauth = auths{i}; 
end;
```

Note: The extra assignment before the DO loop is to force SAS to define the new variable since otherwise the first use will be in the IF condition.  If you already have a LENGTH or other statement that defines FIRSTAUTH then the extra assignment statement is not needed.

Or skip the array and just use the COALESCEC() function to find the first value. And just reverse the order of the variables to also use it to find the last value.

```
firstauth = coalescec(of auth1-auth50);
lastauth = coalescec(of auth50-auth1);
```